# Finding factor for position

Tags: php

I know question title seems quite 'un-understandable', but I don't know how to write question title for this particular question.

Question:
I want to find factor for position.

Let me clear you with an example.

```
Value          Factor
[Available]    [Have to find out] 
----------------------------------
1               10
3               10
9               10
10              10
11              10
25              10
50              10
75              10
99              10

100             100
101             100
105             100
111             100
127             100
389             100
692             100
905             100
999             100

1000            1000
1099            1000
1111            1000
4500            1000
6825            1000
7789            1000
9999            1000

10000           10000
10099           10000
51234           10000
98524           10000
99999           10000

100000          100000
```

and so on.

I hope you understand what I mean to get.

Comment: Shouldn't the "factor" for the first 3 rows be 1, and not 10?

Comment: This may help: http://www.hashbangcode.com/blog/rounding-number-nearest-thousand-php-20.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the first three values should be 1 (as noted by Asaph), then you just need to use all that [logarithm](http://php.net/manual/en/function.log10.php) stuff you learned in school:

```
pow(10, floor(log10($n)))
```

So, how does this work? The base-10 logarithm of a number `x` is the `y` such that `10^y = x` (where `^` stands for exponentiation). This gives us the following:

```
log(  1) 0
log( 10) 1
log(100) 2
...
```

So the `log10` of a number between 1 and 10 will be between 0 and 1, the `log10` of a number between 10 and 100 will be between 1 and 2, etc. The `floor` function will give you the integer part of the logarithm (we're only dealing with non-negative values here so there's no need to worry about which direction `floor` goes with negative values) so `floor(log10())` will be 0 for for anything between 1 and 10, 1 for anything between 10 and 100, etc. Now we have how many factors of ten we need so a simple `pow(10, ...)` gives us the final result.

References:

- [log10](http://php.net/manual/en/function.log10.php)
- [floor](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php)
- [pow](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php)

Answer (score 2):

I'm still a little unsure of what you're asking, but it seems like you want to map values to other values...  In php arrays can be indexed with anything (making them a map).  If 999 always means a factor of 100 and 1099 always means a factor of 1000, you can set the value of array[999] to 100 and the value of array[1099] to 1000, etc.

Comment: It seems like this approach might use a lot of memory.

Comment: Yeah, I totally missed the pattern he was looking for.  A map would use more memory than necessary in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Basically `Factor` is `10` to the power of number of digits in `$value` minus `1` (except for the single digit numbers):

```
if($value < 10) {
  $value += 10;
}
$numOfDigits = count(str_split($value,1));
$factor = pow(10,$numDigits-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This function should work for you. It seems like the first 3 "factors" in your list don't fit the pattern. If, in your sample data set, those first 3 "factors" should really be `1` instead of `10`, then you can safely remove the first 3 lines of the body of the function below.

```
function getFactor($num) {
    if ($num < 10) { // If the first 3 "factors" listed
        return 10;  // in the question should be 1 instead of 10
    }               // then remove these 3 lines.
    $factor = 1;
    while($factor <= $num) {
        $factor *= 10;
    }
    return $factor / 10;
}
```